# Tangent space on a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I am quite new in the topic and I have maybe a strange question.
Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider a $m$ dimensional linear subspace $W$ (so $W = span(w_1, ..., w_m)$ ) of  $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If you want to calculate the tangent space on a particular point on $W$. How to do this?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The tangent space at any point of $W$ is simply $W$ (at least for the most basic definition of tangent space).

If (as in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*) your notion of a tangent space is that it's a set of *pairs* $(p; v)$, where $p$ is an element of your manifold, and $v$ is a vector tangent to your manifold at $p$, then your set of pairs at the point $w \in W$ is just

$$
T_wW = \{(w; u)  \mid u \in W \}.
$$